# How can I get exact URL from the website?

Tags: url, web-scraping

I'm not really sure how to frame the question (maybe the reason why I could not find the answer, so please let me know if it's duplicated question) but I'm not able to get the exact address for a website that I want to scrape. 
 The website address is "https://www.nysar.com/find-a-realtor/".  
 And I want to only scrape information in `Albany, NY`. And when I search by the address with Albany, NY, I get new search results but the URL is still the same.... 
Is there any way that I can find out the detailed URL address? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is dynamically loaded using javascript, so in order to see the source of your search result, you have to go into the Developer tools of your browser and look for it under Network/XHR. There's a lot of information [about this, including here](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/web-scraping-discovering-hidden-apis/). It's not a simple concept so you should study up on it before attempting to scrape this type of sites.

In any event, [in this particular case, the data is extracted from here.](https://webapi.nysar.com/realtor-finder/search?lat=42.6525793&lng=-73.7562317&type=realtor&designations=&name=)